# jess multislot value matching ignoring the order

Tags: jess

I am trying to check if there already exists the same instance or not.

```
(defemplate justificand (slot consq) (multislot antes))
(assert (justificand (consq s) (antes p q r))) ;;; order p q r

(defrule test
   (exists (justificand (consq s) (antes q p r))) ;;; order q p r
    =>
   (printout t "matching success " crlf))
```

In my case, I assert a justificand with (antes p q r) but the order of p, q and r
is not important. So, test rule need to succeed even if it test with (antes q p r).

But, jess seems to consider order of multislot values for matching.

Any method to ignore the order of multislot values for matching?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With your deftemplate and this function

```
(deffunction unleq (?l1 $?l2)
  (and (eq (length$ ?l1)(length$ $?l2))
       (eq (length$ ?l1)(length$ (intersection$ ?l1 $?l2)))))
```

and inserting facts:

```
(deffacts f1
  (justificand (consq s1) (antes p q r))
  (justificand (consq s2) (antes r p q))
  (justificand (consq s3) (antes p q x))
  (justificand (consq s4) (antes p q))
  (justificand (consq s4) (antes r q q p p)))
```

this rule fires:

```
(defrule match
  (justificand (consq ?s) (antes $?pqr&:(unleq $?pqr p q r)))
=>
  (printout t "match for " ?s crlf))
```

giving

```
match for s2
match for s1
```